# How to use numeral.js from app.locals in script of my jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am having trouble using numeral.js in the script part of my jade file.

I have numeral in locals as such:

```
app.locals.numeral = require('numeral');
```

Then in my jade file I want to numeral a variable and format it to dollars, but every time I do it it gets $0.00 so it seems to not be getting the variable correctly.  if i just hard code a number is to works great.

example:

```
 script.
  $('#calculate').click(function() {
    var contracts = 0;
    var premium = 0;
    var size = 0;
    var proceeds = 0;
    var myresult = 0;
    contracts = $('#contracts').val();
    premium = $('#premium').val();
    size = $('input:radio[name=size]:checked').val();
    myresult = (contracts * premium * size);
    proceeds = "#{numeral(" + myresult + ").format('$0.00')}";
    alert(proceeds);
  });
```

so specific line I'm having trouble with is:

```
proceeds = "#{numeral(" + myresult + ").format('$0.00')}";
```

Individually all the numbers work and if I don't use numeral I get the right outcome, but as soon as I numeral I get $0.00.

Not sure what how to get it to see the variable myresult, I've tried many combinations.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up accessing numeral this way and for this one page I included the entire js file in a script tag like such:

```
script(src='/javascripts/numeral.min.js')
```

And then:

```
proceeds = numeral(myresult).format('$0.00');
```

Not sure this is ideal but it works.